# (response.ok === false) { setError('show')

Tags: reactjs

I get a 400 bad request when typing less than 5 characters in a textarea. And I am trying to show an error message to the user when he/she inputs a text message that is too short. But the message won't show up.

```
    const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: newThought })
      }

    fetch(HAPPY_THOUGHTS_URL, options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((response => {
        if (response.ok === false) { 
          setError('show')
        } else { 
          fetchThoughtsList()
        }
      })) 
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  } 

......

  return (
   <div> 
     {error === 'show' && 
        <ErrorPopup
          message="Oops, your message needs to be more than 4 characters. Please give it one more try!" 
          setError={setError} 
        />
      }
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: To me this `response.ok === false` looks odd. why re-invent the wheel? `response.ok` => do what you want to do when its OK such as `fetchThoughtsList()`, in ur case. then do `else` to `setError('show')`. also in render why `error === 'show'`? simply set `error` as `null` and do `error ' &&  ...// rest of ur code`. It may not fix the issue but said it in general

Comment: now about the issue, can you validate that the `if`, inside ur `fetch` gets executed? Try adding `console.log("inside if")` and inside `else `console.log("else")` to see if any of these messages appear in console. Plz update it afterwards what you get in console.

Comment: Thanks for your comments on the code. I am completely new to React and practicing JavaScript so therefore still need to think out loud in my code. I ` console.log(response.ok)` which comes out false. Nothing shows when I console.log inside if and inside else the message I wrote shows, but the fetchThoughtsList come out as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the order of events, in your first `then` you can read `ok` field, but in the second one, there is just data you get from calling `json`. Try something like this instead

```
 fetch(HAPPY_THOUGHTS_URL, options)
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) { 
      setError('show');
      return null;
    } 
    return response.json();
   }) 
  .then(response => {
    if (response) {
      fetchThoughtsList()
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

I assume you just didn't include the part where you're processing response data, but if you really don't do anything with it, you don't need `response.json()` and the second `then`:

```
 fetch(HAPPY_THOUGHTS_URL, options)
 .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) { 
      fetchThoughtsList()
    } 
    else{ 
      setError('show');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

try inserting `.then(response => {console.log('actual ok value',response.ok); return response}` as the first `then` and see what it prints, maybe the response is indeed `ok`

Comment: Nadia! Now I remembered my teacher talking about the first and the second promise and you are completely right! Thank you for clarifying that :) Still haven't gotten the error message to show, but I'll work on that.

Comment: Added something you may want to try :)

Comment: Thank you again! `actual ok value false` when less than 5 characters. And true on more than 5 char, but still no error message showing when false.

Comment: And if you add `console.log('error value', error)` right before `return` of the component?

Comment: It starts out as `error value hide` and when `actual ok value false` it logs `error value show`

Comment: There might be something with the error component, I'd try replacing it with a simple div just to check

Comment: Thank you for your kind and helpful comments! :) I have found something that works now: `fetch(HAPPY_THOUGHTS_URL, options)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        setError(true)
        throw new Error ('Ups, something went wrong')
      } else { 
        setNewThought('')
        return response.json()
      }
    })
    .then(recievedThought => setThoughtsList([recievedThought, ...thoughtsList]))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  } `

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad you've found something that works for you

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(API_URL, options)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        setError(true)
        throw new Error ('Ups, something went wrong')
      } else { 
        setNewThought('')
        return response.json()
      }
    })
    .then(recievedThought => setThoughtsList([recievedThought, ...thoughtsList]))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
```